# error Sorry, you are not allowed to post with this username

Tags: node.js, wordpress, axios, upload

I used the following code to upload the file from node js to Wordpress;

app.js codes:

```
axios = require('axios');
FormData = require('form-data');

socket.on('uploadFile', function (data) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", data);
    axios.post('https://fxalion.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
});
```

my custom js codes:

```
$('.uploadFile').on('submit',function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
    socket.emit('uploadFile', imagefile.files[0]);
});
```

my html codes:

```
<form class="uploadFile h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="file" id="file" class="form-control" aria-label="file example" required>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">آپلود</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But I get this error:

```
data: {
      code: 'rest_cannot_create',
      message: 'Sorry, you are not allowed to post with this username.',
      data: { status: 401 }
    }
```

please help me...

Comment: How do you communicate your username to `fxalion.com`? It does not appear anywhere in the request that you make?

Comment: I did not transfer the username to fxalion.com anywhere.
How should I do?

Comment: I don't know the API, but must certainly authenticate your request somehow. Without a username, the error message is expected.